# How to add folder to grunt dist

Tags: gruntjs, famo.us

Probably pretty simple but how can I make sure than when I build my app with "grunt" that it includes a custom "content" folder where I have image resources and etc.?

Currently when I do "grunt" it only includes 'css', 'lib', 'src' and 'index.html'

Answer (score 4):

You can use [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) and appoint which files to be copied in the dist folder when you build your app.

Example config:

```
copy: {
  main: {
    src: 'content/*',
    dest: 'dist/',
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put your own directory inside [appname]/app/ .. eg. [appname]/app/custom/, it will get copied into [appname]/dist/  when you run 'grunt'.

That's at least the behavior on my end.. Hope it helps!

Comment: That's strange because this is how I have it setup, I'm even using the boilerplate layout (content/images) but 'content' and subfolders/items do not get added to dist.

Comment: PS: I have to do --force because of warnings in my JS, but that wouldn't affect it would it?

Comment: Yea.. if those are style warnings, they can be disabled.. Here is my Gruntfile.js file. It has eslint and jscs commented out so you will not get style warnings.. https://gist.github.com/john45traver/48625c571efc647be3d7

Comment: Thanks for that link, my grunt file is completely different -https://gist.github.com/skaraman/b7e64f8a4153d3fe95b3 . I completely cleared all the warnings and errors to avoid using --force and grunt still does not add the content folder :-/

Comment: Try adding the copy config highlighted here.. https://gist.github.com/john45traver/48625c571efc647be3d7#file-gruntfile-js-L188 between lines 19-20 in your gruntfile

Comment: added that bit, still does not add the folder, check gist for updated file syntax, PS - I'll be predisposed shortly, but I really appreciate your help so far, anything else that you could recommend I'll try later tonight.

Comment: Yea sorry I can't test anything, with that config, I assume you are not on a Mac or else you would get the same Gruntfile as I have.. I'll ping the author of the tool.. @theAlphNerd .. Can you help with this?

Comment: Yeah, I'm on PC (windows 7)